# How to get Constructor Method Reference using reflection in Java

Tags: java, lambda, constructor, java-8, method-reference

I have a library that I am using in a project. It has a class which can be instantiated as

`A object = new A(new B(value), C::new, D::new);`

None of the classes A, B, C, D are public, although the constructors are.

So, I want to use Reflection to achieve this. But, I can't figure out how to do method reference `C::new`, `D::new` using reflection.

Would appreciate any pointers on how I can do this.

Comment: any good reason why you are going against library design?

Comment: `C.class.newInstance()`? I'm not getting your question ...

Comment: So you expect us to guess the parameter types?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that a constructor reference is used is not important. You just need to know the functional interface type into which it is converted, and then create an instance of that.

In the case of a default constructor, this would probably be `Supplier<...>`. You'd get something like this:

```
Class<C> cKlass = ...;
Constructor<C> cCons = cKlass.getDeclaredConstructor();

Supplier<C> cSupp = () -> { // similarly for class D
        try {
            return cCons.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can not default construct " + cKlass, e);
        }
};

...

Class<A> aKlass = ...;
Constructor<A> aCons = aKlass.getDeclaredConstructor(B.class, Supplier.class, Supplier.class);
A a = aCons.newInstance(b, cSupp, dSupp);
```